# Why does Rails namespace routing place the action name first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

Mostly a question of curiosity; I couldn't find an answer from the great Google, and it's something that has interested me for a while.

```
# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

# produces a rout helper such as:
edit_admin_user_path
```

What is the rationale behind that format instead of:

```
admin_edit_user_path
```

It makes sense to me to put the namespace first, since that's the purpose of a namespace...

Or even cleaner, I think, would be something like:

```
admin_user_edit_path # id, <namespace>_<resource>_<action>_path
```

Going from the least specific to most specific seems logical to me, yet I suspect the folks who wrote the Rails framework are smarter than me, so they must have had a reason for doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the rational is to put the HTTP/controller Action first. So if you have a single controller/route that has all the crud operations, you can quickly distinguish which is which just by reading the first part instead of searching the string for the action

```
admin_user_path
new_admin_user_path
edit_admin_user_path
```

Comment: That does make some sense, now that I think about it.  Allows one to see the CRUD easily from scanning the routes.